# Adding to or updating an entity in a foreach loop takes too long time before calling SaveChanges()?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this method that saves an entity with its related items (many-to-many relationship),

```
private static void Save<T>(TbCommonHistoryLog log, List<T> lstDetails) where T : IHasSerial
{   
    foreach (var item in lstDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Serial))
    {
        var ser = SerializeObject(item);
        var record = oContext.TbHistoryLog_Lists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ListObjectJson == ser);
        if (record == null) //add new list item
        {
            TbCommonHistoryLog_Lists listObject = new TbCommonHistoryLog_Lists()
            {
                ListObjectJson = SerializeObject(item)
            };
            var details = new TbCommonHistoryLogDetails { TbHistoryLog = log, TbHistoryLog_Lists = listObject };
            oContext.TbHistoryLogDetails.Add(details);
        }
        else //attach an existing list item
        {
            var o = oContext.TbHistoryLog_Lists.Find(record.Id);
            oContext.TbHistoryLog_Lists.Attach(o);
            var details = new TbCommonHistoryLogDetails { TbHistoryLog = log, TbHistoryLog_Lists = o };
            oContext.TbHistoryLogDetails.Add(details);
        }
    }
    oContext.BulkSaveChanges();
}
```

I have two tables: `TbCommonHistoryLog`, `TbCommonHistoryLog_Lists`, that are in many to many relationship, the joining table is `TbCommonHistoryLogDetails`,
What I'm doing here is an auditing for master-detail models, all audits are serialized to JSON in DB, I save the head object in the `TbCommonHistoryLog` table, and every list item in the `TbHistoryLog_Lists` table, in the mthod above I check if the list item is already exists in the database or not to avoid duplicating. 
but this process takes more than 15 seconds which is a very long time, I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.. please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every single item in collection you're querying database. My suggestion is to save records in var, then ask the variable if the item is in database.

```
var databaseRecords = oContext.TbHistoryLog_Lists.ToList();
```

Then in the loop:

```
var record = databaseRecords.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ListObjectJson == ser);
```